# Continue while loop without including continue statement inside the loop

Tags: php

I have a part in my code:

```
while($a = getrow()){
//code
}
```

`getrow()` is a function which keeps on returning array based on some condition.

what `getrow()` should return so that the while loop doesn't execute the code inside but takes the next value returned by getrow() function.

Comment: Please check my answer and see if it works for you and accept it if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While loops will run as long as the condition remains `true`. So as long as you return rows, the code inside will get executed. If you return false, the while loop will terminate. If you want to conditionally avoid running code within the loop, your option is to return something like 'SKIP' and then inside the while loop check if `$a == 'SKIP'` and then issue a `continue`.

```
while($a = getrow()){
    if($a == 'SKIP')
        continue;
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `continue` `control` `structure` for skip an `iteration`. Please read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

```
 while($a = getrow()){
        if($a == 'something'){
            continue; // skip iteration
         }
        //rest code which you want to run
    }
```